# PHP select input calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

I'm looking to see if there's anything that does this out there / someone has already done it and outsourced the code before I write the code myself.

I have the following date selection:

[image]

I want to make it so that when you select a month the correct amount of days for the month are automatically shown in the day drop down. My idea to do this myself is use JQuery to detect when a user selects a month and then manually .hide the select days that should not be there.

Anything else out there that does this?

Comment: Does it support the UI I'm trying to go with? The JQuery date picker standard UI simply drops a calendar below the input field.

Comment: no its different to the format you want. But used widely. But what you are looking to do would only take a few lines of code anyway.

Comment: Few lines of code? Please care to explain...

Comment: just use the change evt and hide the dates that arent needed. a really easy way to do this is to apply a css class to your date select, e.g. "jan" all dates shown, feb 29, 30,31 hidden (febleap 30,31) or just do it with js

Comment: Done it with JS using a switch method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using HTML5 input type=date

```
<input type="date" />
```

Try it here [Tryit Editor -W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type)

Comment: Looking to find a solution with my current UI

Comment: Which UI are you using? Twitter Boostrap?

Comment: I mean just the UI I've conjured up. Not using anything!

Comment: I understand. You dont want use a datepicker like this [Datepicker for Bootstrap 3](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I suggest to create the algorimt via jQuery.

Comment: Make sure you treat bissextile year, to give Feb a extra day. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95876/discussion-between-liam-macmillan-and-vinicius-fagundes).